# Rewriting definite integral as a Riemann sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

If I were to rewrite $\int_{0}^h x^2$as a riemann sum, will $\delta(x)$ be $\frac{(h-0)}{n} $and $x_i$ be $(0+\frac{h}{n} i)$ and $f(x_i)$ be $(\frac{hi}{n})^2$? where $i = 1$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$ for the riemann sum? I think I'm doing something wrong as I get 3 variables.

Comment: What you wrote looks correct.  It would look nicer with [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  $\Delta x$ simplifies to $h/n$, and $x_i$ simplifies to $hi/n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^h x^2dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\dfrac{hi}n\right)^2\dfrac hn=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{h^3}{n^3}\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni^2=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{h^3}{n^3}\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6=\dfrac13h^3$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If $f $ is Riemann integrable at $[a,b]$, then the Riemann sums goe to the integral of $f $ over $[a,b]$ which means, in particular, that

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(a+k\frac{b-a}{n})=\int_a^bf$$

in your case,

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac hn\sum_{k=1}^n(0+\frac hn k)^2=\int_0^hx^2dx=\frac{h^3}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!